# Terminated due to timeout

Tags: c, memory, timeout

I was solving [*this question*](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/filling-jars) on hackerrank. The code I submitted is working for 6 out of 13 test cases. For the rest of the test cases the error is **Terminated due to timeout.**

**Problem Statement**

Animesh has N empty candy jars, numbered from 1 to N, with infinite capacity. He performs M operations. Each operation is described by 3 integers, a, b, and k. Here, a and b are indices of the jars, and k is the number of candies to be added inside each jar whose index lies between a and b (both inclusive). Can you tell the average number of candies after M operations?

**Input Format**

The first line contains two integers, N and M, separated by a single space. 
M lines follow; each of them contains three integers, a, b, and k, separated by spaces.

**Constraints**

3≤N≤10^7

1≤M≤10^5

1≤a≤b≤N

0≤k≤10^6

**Output Format**

A single line containing the average number of candies across N jars, rounded down to the nearest integer.

**Note:** Rounded down means finding the greatest integer which is less than or equal to the given number. E.g. 13.65 and 13.23 are rounded down to 13, while 12.98 is rounded down to 12.

**Sample Input**

```
5 3
1 2 100
2 5 100
3 4 100
```

**Sample Output**

160

**Explanation**

Initially each of the jars contains 0 candies

0 0 0 0 0
First operation:

100 100 0 0 0
Second operation:

100 200 100 100 100
Third operation:

100 200 200 200 100
Total = 800, Average = 800/5 = 160

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define size 50
int main() {

    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */    
    long n,m,a,b,k,*arr,i=0,sum=0;
    char *buff=NULL;

    buff=malloc(50);
    if(fgets(buff,size,stdin)!=NULL)
    {
        if(strlen(buff)>0 && buff[strlen(buff)-1]=='\n')
            buff[strlen(buff)-1]='\0';
        sscanf(buff,"%ld %ld",&n,&m);

    }
    else
        exit(0);

    arr=malloc(sizeof(long)*n+1);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        arr[i]=0;

    i=0;    
    while(i++<m)
    {
        if(fgets(buff,size,stdin)!=NULL)
        {
            if(strlen(buff)>0 && buff[strlen(buff)-1]=='\n')
                buff[strlen(buff)-1]='\0';
            sscanf(buff,"%ld %ld %ld",&a,&b,&k);

            while(a<=b)
            {
                arr[a-1]+=k;
                a++;
            }

        }
        else
            exit(0);      

    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        sum+=arr[i];

    printf("%ld",sum/n);

    return 0;
}
```

The code is not working for these test cases

[**Input**](https://hr-testcases.s3.amazonaws.com/1637/input07.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1426446875&Signature=Y37QHJoyEXP6SpKATLQBkxs7ubo%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)

[**Output**](https://hr-testcases.s3.amazonaws.com/1637/output07.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1426446870&Signature=SxahQwRlxZRlLJk%2B2SB1kYwhTjU%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)

Comment: You should write this as a solution.. I changed the code and it got accepted! Yay! Thanks @JimLewis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the average without needing to know the final number of candies in each jar. All you need is the number of jars N and the total number of candies added in each operation.